# Sorting the date column in calendar order in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to sort the date column in R in calendar order. like begining from "Jan-16", "Feb-16", "Mar-16" or beginning with recent month "May-16", "Apr-16" and "Mar-16".

Regards,
Mohan

Comment: One clarification, does "May-16" stand for 16th day of May, as I interpreted below, or May 2016? I can edit my answer to cover the second situation if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add the year, and then convert the vector to the `Date` class:

```
# dates
dates <- c("Jan-16", "Feb-16", "Mar-16")
# convert to date class
dates <- as.Date(paste0("2016-", dates), format="%Y-%b-%d")

# get most recent date
max(dates)
# sort
sort(dates, decreasing=T)
```

Comment: SO is usually opposed to questions to asking for package recommendations.  You may take a look at `lubridate` and `zoo`. I don't use them, so I can't tell you if either contains such a thing.

Comment: @Imo Thanks for the suggestion. I have checked those packages. But, it didn't fit into the requirement. I have taken your suggestion. Thanks for the details....